# Multiple background-image urls: apply css style that appends onto url list instead of replacing

Tags: css

It's possible to supply a list of urls to the background-image property:

```
background-image:url('imageA.jpg'),url('imageB.jpg');
```

Is it possible for another css style to simply append to this list, rather than override it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fAddBackgroundImage(oElem, sUrl) {
  oElem.style.backgroundImage = `${getComputedStyle(oElem).backgroundImage}, url('${sUrl}')`;
  return getComputedStyle(oElem).backgroundImage;
}
console.log( fAddBackgroundImage(document.querySelector('.bg'), 'imageC.jpg') );
```

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url('imageA.jpg'), url('imageB.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```